# How to change the order the styles tag are added

Tags: css, reactjs, less, antd

I'm trying to override a class style from ant design but looks like my custom style is the one being overridden due to the order the styles are rendered on the html page.

I've already tried to change the order of the import of my custom style to be the first thing to be imported on my component but it seams that this doesn't do anything.

My element style looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to change the order the style is added to the page? Or make my style render last?

Comment: the import of your custom style must be the _last_ thing to be imported, if you want override smthg.

Comment: It is already the last thing I'm importing on my component

Comment: if there are few css properties then you can add !important; for each property

Comment: if this doesn't help then please create an code snippet or jsfiddle link

Comment: I don't want to use `!important`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to override some style without using `!important`, you could increase the specification of your selector. Specifying that you are selecting a div, for example, will add more priority and override it, like changing `.ant-form-inline .ant-form-item` to `.ant-form-inline div.ant-form-item`.

Comment: Perfect that fixed it. Thank you so much :D

Comment: I'm glad it works. Could you choose it as the correct answer than?

Comment: Yes I'm waiting because stack overflow has a time limit to choose an answer as correct after posting a question. You were too quick :p

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it. I should ask more questions :D

Comment: Done ;) Thank tou again